# Display WordPress RSS Feed Thumbnail

Tags: rss, feed

I was fetching my blog posts from another WordPress site to another WordPress site. The issue I'm facing now is how to display the RSS Feed thumbnail.

See my code below.

```
<div class="row blog__container--row2">
   <?php
   $feed_url = 'https://www.alphawebtips.com/feed/';

   // Fetch the feed using SimplePie library
   require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
   $rss = fetch_feed($feed_url);

   if (!is_wp_error($rss)) {
   // Set the number of posts to display
   $max_items = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);
   $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $max_items);
   }
   ?>

   <?php if ($max_items == 0) : ?>
   <div>No posts found.</div>
   <?php else : ?>
        <?php foreach ($rss_items as $item) : ?>
             <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog__wrapper">
                       <div class="blog--single mb-3">
                            <h3><a href="<?php echo esc_url($item->get_permalink()); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo esc_html($item->get_title()); ?></a></h3>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($item->get_permalink()); ?>" target="_blank">Read More</a>
                       </div>
                  </div>

             </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   
</div>
```

What can I do to display the thumbnail? None of the WordPress functions/API works.